# How to get rid of System.__Canon in debugger of Visual Studio?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Visual Studio's debugger behaves strangely when I use combination of generic reference type with generic struct:

```
class C<T>
{
    public T ClassItem { get; set; }
}

struct S<T>
{
    public T StructItem;
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var foo = new C<S<string>> {ClassItem = new S<string> {StructItem = "Bar"}};
    }
}
```

When I'm trying to peek at ClassItem field, I'm seeing strange `System.__Canon` instead of actual contents of the field:

[image: screenshot of the debugger]

Actually, there is the way to peek at struct contents, if I add this line to the Watch window: `((S<string>) foo.ClassItem).StructItem`. In this case I can see the "Bar" string. But it is a big pain with large projects and more complex types. So is there a way to get the debugger to behave normally?

I have two versions of Visual Studio: 2013 and 2015, both of them behave the same way.

Answer (score 4):

You can look into [.NET source containing System.__Canon](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/object.cs,a210e11a9e5f2deb)

According to comment before it, it seems that this class is required for generic types instantiating.

The similar question is asked on [msdn](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/5f18534c-c6d6-4292-ba53-1edf80b3b0bd/what-is-the-purpose-of-systemcanon-?forum=netfxremoting)

According to article on [codeproject](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/20481/NET-Type-Internals-From-a-Microsoft-CLR-Perspecti):

> For each closed Generic Type that is supplied with a Value Type for a
>   Type Parameter, CLR creates a new type during runtime and uses it for
>   instantiations and other purposes. For all closed Generic Types of a
>   given Generic Type that is supplied with a Reference Type, CLR creates
>   one type where the Type Parameter for which a Reference Type is
>   supplied, is replaced with a special type named System.__Canon.

Comment: The msdn question is related to some bug in .net 2.0 and it seems outdated a little. The purpose of __Canon is clearer to me now, but that was not the question. The question was about poor debugger abilities in displaying struct contents. It seems like the only way is to replace `struct S<T>` with a class.